# Запустить таймер, когда убирается курсор с блока

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть блок который постоянно видимый, и есть один скрытый блок. Когда мы кликаем на видимый, видимый скрываеться и появляется скрытый. Когда мы уводим курсор с этого блока начинаеться отсчет таймера 2 сек. и он меняеться на прежний блок.

Вопрос. Как сделать что-бы когда мы уводили курсор с блока и сработывал таймер, можно было обратно его навести пока он не исчез и остановить этот таймер.

**Пример** http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/15/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавим [пару строчек кода](http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/16/):

```
var setTimeoutID; // используем для запоминания id setTimeout

$('#click').click(function () {
    $('.none').stop().hide();
    $('.youremail').stop().show();
});

$('.youremail').mouseleave(function () {
    setTimeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.youremail').stop().hide();
        $('.none').stop().show();
    }, 2000);
});

$('.youremail').mouseenter(function () {
    clearTimeout(setTimeoutID); // отмена таймера
});

$('#closeinner').click(function () {
    $('.youremail').stop().hide();
    $('.none').stop().show();
});
```